# How to pass Report Parameter value to SSRS Report(CAMEL Based) Calling Sharepoint asmx

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008, parameter-passing, camel-sql

I am not able to pass report parameter. Parameter value is not getting replaced by actual value passed. I checked the fiddler. actual value is not getting replaced.

I have tried =Parameters!XXX.Value in replace of parameter did not work

XXXXXX
            
            
                {XXXXXXXXX}
            
            
                
                     
             
                               
                                 
                                 
                                    
                                 
                               
                        
                    
                
            
            
                
                    
                        FALSE
                        False
                    
                
            
        
    
 *